# Facebook login and fetching profile info

Tags: spring, facebook-login

I am doing a project on JSF2.0 and Spring 3.0.2. Now my requirement is to login with facebook and fetching profile information.

Can anyone give me some link or advice so that I can proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring has subproject called spring social. There are tutorials that should get you started. Loging in and getting profile information is pretty streight forward. Have a look at this [quickstart](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social/wiki/Quick-Start).

Comment: when I am redirecting to this url ::
 String url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="+api_key+"&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token";
Its working fine. But when I changed the redirection_uri, i am getting an error.

Comment: You need to be more specific if you want some help, what error?